# Hash in url and string comparison thereof subject to timing attack in php?

Tags: php, security, password-recovery

I'm somewhat auditing the security of my password reset email system.  It's standard, using a link to the email like this:

```
example.com/password-reset?code=Ik5S7eubvs79nxFCNx04Vdn5RNfb%2BUJRhC0khoHtuHU%3D
```

That code urldecodes to a bcrypt hash, which is matched against a hash generated in the database at the time a password reset is requested (and an expiration timeout of 24 hours).

I believe this approach is pretty standard, however, reading this article on the topic:
https://blog.jcoglan.com/2012/06/09/why-you-should-never-use-hash-functions-for-message-authentication/
, the author mentions that there is a timing attack implicit in doing a regular `==` comparison on two strings, in the theory that any such comparison will be optimized to check character by character and reject based on the first mismatched character.  That would then allow an attacker to "walk" brute force their way through a string to eventually build up a match.   Is this *actually* a security concern in php, though?

I'm guessing that with network latency and the fast speed of the == operation in php, such a timing attack is practically impossible on trivially short strings, because it would always be masked by random noise in the time stuff takes over the network.  Obviously the fix is short (compare hashes of the hashes or something horrible like that) for my case, but I'm interested if this is actually a pragmatic concern for me to watch out for.

Comment: A function to avoid precisely this attack [has been accepted for the next version of PHP](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/timing_attack), after [much discussion of the details and surrounding issues](http://marc.info/?t=138773222700002&r=1&w=2)

Comment: How is the code stored in the database, did you store the BCrypt hash directly as sent in the encoded url, or did you store a hash of it? Timing attacks seem to be a problem mainly if somebody has access to the server, see the ongoing [Password Hashing Competition](https://password-hashing.net/faq.html#qa).

Answer (score 1):

I think a timed seed is a poor choice, even if your hashes are short-lived and tied to specific users. You need to asume that your source code is compromised (even if it's not). I'd use openssl_random_pseudo_bytes() instead. You should also limit the user's ability to ask for a password reset, too (e.g. no more than a number of times a day/week/etc.)

Comment: I do actually use openssl_random_pseudo_bytes (via php bcrypt) to create the nonce.

Comment: That's nice. Then the only thing left to severely limit the possibility of a timed attack is a constraint on the number of times per day a particular user can ask for a password reset.